# Как создать сетку, где в первом ряду одно количество колонок, а в остальных — другое?

Tags: css, grid

Условие - можно использовать только CSS (Использовать JavaScript и ломать верстку нельзя)

Нужно сделать:

Первый ряд - 2 колонки
Остальные ряды - 3 колонки

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
    <div class="col">10</div>
  </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну сделайте 6 колонок, у первого ряда элементы занимают по три колонки, у остальных по две

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того, как это сделать.

```css
.grid-container {
  width:100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.grid-child{
  display:flex;
  height:70px;
  background-color:blue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-container > :nth-child(1),
.grid-container > :nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  <div class="grid-child"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это что нужно было)

Answer (score 0):

Решение с точно таким же html, как и у вас

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 230px;
}

.col {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 108px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 108px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.col:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col:nth-child(3)::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(3)::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(4) {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(5) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(5)::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(5)::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(6) {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(7) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(7)::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(7)::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(8) {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(9) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(9)::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(9)::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-child(10) {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
        <div class="col">8</div>
        <div class="col">9</div>
        <div class="col">10</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно сделать: Первый ряд - 2 колонки Остальные ряды - 3 колонки

Предложу такой вариант...

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.row > div {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.row > div:nth-child(1),
.row > div:nth-child(2) {
  /* Занимает один ряд и
  растягивается на две колонки */
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="col">9</div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
</div>
```